# How to create two columns from DataFrame in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am praticing this [apache spark machine learning example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-collaborative-filtering.html) to make a recommendation system for our users based on ratings they gave and I got this data which is top 10 recommendation product for a userId 31511 ( check out the last code of example above)

```
 scala> results.show
 +------+--------------------+
 |userId|     recommendations|
 +------+--------------------+
 | 31511|[[328, 0.7845393]...|
 +------+--------------------+

scala> results.printSchema
root
 |-- userId: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- recommendations: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- productionId: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rating: float (nullable = true)
```

and I want to know how to create another DataFrame from variable "results" that looks like this

```
+------------+------+
|productionId|rating|
+------------+------+
|          1 |     1|
+------------+------+
|          2 |   4.5|
+------------+------+
|          3 |     5|
+------------+------+
|          4 |   2.5|
+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just explode and select

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode}

results.select(explode($"recommendations") as "recommendations").select(
  col("recommendations.*")
)
```